# Android Send MMS not work

Tags: android, mms, android-mms

What's wrong with my code ?
I try to make as simple as possible.

```
 public static void sendMMS(final Context context, String phoneNumber, String messageText) throws Exception {

        final String fileName = "send." + String.valueOf(Math.abs(new Random().nextLong())) + ".dat";
        File mSendFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), fileName);
        final byte[] pdu = MmsMessagingDemo.buildPdu(context, phoneNumber, "hello", messageText);
        FileOutputStream writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileOutputStream(mSendFile);
            writer.write(pdu);
        }
        finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
        Uri writerUri = (new Uri.Builder())
                .authority("com.example.android.apis.os.MmsFileProvider")
                .path(fileName)
                .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)
                .build();

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendMultimediaMessage(context, writerUri, null, null, null);


}
```

This methode called in AsyncTask
I make app defaut smsApp

```
 public void makeDefautSmsApp() {
        final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
        if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, myPackageName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

I make all permission I can

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
```

And in manifest

```
<manifest package="com.example.sendsms"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- SMS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But i have no error but my message not send
MMSManager.sendMMS(MainActivity.this, "+33628xxxxxx", "helloWorld");

Maybe someone have an idea ?

Comment: Post your manifest.xml file. Does it give you an error?

Comment: @MRah update. It's 3 days i m on it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my probleme, because i sand mms to the same phone who sand it.
It's work for sms but it's look like not work for mms.

But if i sand mms to an other phone it's work